# WinError 10061 in scrapy+scrapy-selenium program

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scrapy

I have created a scrapy + scrapy-selenium bot, and after some time of successfully scraping data from the website it returned me the following error

```
2023-02-22 06:12:38 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: DELETE http://l
ocalhost:58736/session/ec60bfa108737c8be99566052d54e5d3 {}
2023-02-22 06:12:38 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Resetting dropped connection: localh
ost
2023-02-22 06:12:42 [urllib3.util.retry] DEBUG: Incremented Retry for (url='/session/ec6
0bfa108737c8be99566052d54e5d3'): Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None,
status=None)
2023-02-22 06:12:42 [urllib3.connectionpool] WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=N
one, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionEr
ror('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001FA6D516BE0>: Failed to establi
sh a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target mac
hine actively refused it')': /session/ec60bfa108737c8be99566052d54e5d3
2023-02-22 06:12:42 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTP connection (2): lo
calhost:58736
2023-02-22 06:12:46 [urllib3.util.retry] DEBUG: Incremented Retry for (url='/session/ec6
0bfa108737c8be99566052d54e5d3'): Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None,
status=None)
2023-02-22 06:12:46 [urllib3.connectionpool] WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=N
one, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionEr
ror('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001FA6DAE3D00>: Failed to establi
sh a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target mac
hine actively refused it')': /session/ec60bfa108737c8be99566052d54e5d3
2023-02-22 06:12:46 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTP connection (3): lo
calhost:58736
2023-02-22 06:12:50 [urllib3.util.retry] DEBUG: Incremented Retry for (url='/session/ec6
0bfa108737c8be99566052d54e5d3'): Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None,
status=None)
2023-02-22 06:12:50 [urllib3.connectionpool] WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=N
one, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionEr
ror('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001FA6D63BA30>: Failed to establi
sh a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target mac
hine actively refused it')': /session/ec60bfa108737c8be99566052d54e5d3
2023-02-22 06:12:50 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTP connection (4): lo
calhost:58736
```

What is the reason it occured and what shall be done to fix it?

What I expect:
To get rid of this error and to be able to parse data

My code:

```
#spider code

import scrapy
import time
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
#from scrapy_selenium import
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest
from .. import items
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from PIL import Image
import io


class TournamentCrawlerSpider(Spider):
    name = 'tournament_crawler'
    allowed_domains = ['mafiaworldtour.com']
    start_urls = ['http://mafiaworldtour.com/tournaments']

    def start_requests(self):
        yield SeleniumRequest(url=self.start_urls[0],
                              wait_time=5, screenshot=False, callback=self.click)

    def click(self, response):
        #Image.open(io.BytesIO(response.meta['screenshot'])).save("screen.png")
        browser = response.meta['driver']
        button = browser.find_element(value="/html/body/div[1]/div/section[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/select",
                                      by=By.XPATH)
        button.click()
        time.sleep(5)
        button = browser.find_element(by=By.XPATH,
                                     value='//*[@id="search_year"]/option[6]')
        button.click()
        time.sleep(5)

        button =  browser.find_element(by=By.XPATH,
                                     value='/html/body/div[1]/div/section[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/select')
        button.click()
        time.sleep(5)
        button = browser.find_element(by=By.XPATH,
                                     value="/html/body/div[1]/div/section[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/select/option[5]")
        button.click()
        time.sleep(5)
        next_page = True
        while next_page:
            html = browser.page_source
            response = Selector(text=html)
            tournaments_urls = response.xpath('//header[@class="entity_header"]/h2/a/@href')
            for el in tournaments_urls.extract():
                yield scrapy.Request(url=el, callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True)
            try:
                next_page_button = browser.find_element(by=By.XPATH,
                                                    value="//html/body/div[1]/div/section[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/ul[2]/li[11]/a")
                next_page_button.click()
                time.sleep(2)
                print("next page!!!")
            except:
                print("No next page!!!!!!!!!!")
                next_page = False
                break




    def parse(self,response):
          #  driver = response.meta['driver']
            name = response.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/section[1]/div/div/div/h1/text()').extract_first().replace("Tournament Information - ", "")

            tournament_info = response.xpath("//span[@class='small_content']")




            tournament = items.Tournament()
            tournament['name'] = name
            tournament['city'] = response.xpath('//span[@class="small_content"]/text()')[1].extract()
            print(f"TYPE OF CITY {type(tournament['city'])}")
            tournament['date_of_beginning'] = tournament_info[1].xpath(".//text()").extract_first()
            tournament['duration_days'] = tournament_info[2].xpath(".//text()").extract_first()
            tournament['type_of_participants'] = tournament_info[3].xpath(".//text()").extract_first()
            tournament['participants'] = tournament_info[5].xpath(".//text()").extract_first()
            tournament['category'] = len(tournament_info[6].xpath(".//i"))
            tournament['cost'] = tournament_info[7].xpath(".//text()").extract_first()
            tournament['url'] = response.url
            tournament['type_of_tournament'] = tournament_info[4].xpath(".//text()").extract_first()
            tournament['registration'] = tournament_info[8].xpath(".//text()").extract_first()
            tournament['list_of_participants'] = tournament_info[9].xpath(".//text()").extract_first()
            tournament['social_network_address'] = tournament_info[10].xpath(".//text()").extract_first()
            yield tournament
            yield scrapy.Request(url=response.url + "#players", callback=self.parse_players, dont_filter=True)


    def parse_players(self, response):
            print("PARSE PLAYERS")
            tournament = response.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/section[1]/div/div/div/h1/text()').extract_first().replace("ИНФОРМАЦИЯ О ТУРНИРЕ - ", "").replace("Tournament Information - ", "")
            players = response.xpath('//div[@class="col-md-9"]')[1:-1]
            for player in players:
                item = items.Participant()
                if player.xpath('.//a').extract() != []:
                    print("LINK PRESENT", player.xpath('.//a').extract())
                    nickname = player.xpath(".//a[1]/text()").extract_first()
                    url = player.xpath('.//a/@href').extract_first()
                    name = player.xpath(".//a[2]/text()").extract_first()
                    club = player.xpath('.//text()[4]').extract_first()
                    item['url'] = url
                    item['name'] = name
                    item['nickname'] = nickname
                    item['club'] = club
                    item['tournament'] = tournament
                    yield item
                else:
                    print("ELSE")
                    item['nickname'] = ' '.join(player.xpath(".//text()").getall())
                    item['url'] = None
                    item['name'] = None
                    item['nickname'] = None
                    item['club'] = None
                    item['tournament'] = tournament
                    yield item

            yield scrapy.Request(url=response.url.replace("#players", "#scores"), callback=self.parse_scores, dont_filter=True)


    def parse_scores(self, response):
        players = response.xpath('//div[@class="row with-avatar"]')
        for player in players:
            name = player.xpath('.//div[@class="col-md-9 header-col"]/a/text()').extract_first()
            url = player.xpath('.//div[@class="col-md-9 header-col"]/a/@href').extract_first()
            points = player.xpath('.//div[@class="row with-avatar"]/div[@class="col-md-1 header-col "]/text()').extract_first()
            item = items.MWTBalls()
            item['tournament'] = response.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/section[1]/div/div/div/h1/text()').extract_first().replace("ИНФОРМАЦИЯ О ТУРНИРЕ - ", "").replace("Tournament Information - ", "")
            item['nickname'] = name
            item['points'] = points
            item['url'] = url
            yield item
        yield scrapy.Request(url=response.url.replace("#scores", "#results"), callback=self.parse_tables,
                             dont_filter=True)



    def parse_tables(self, response):
        tournament = response.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/section[1]/div/div/div/h1/text()').extract_first().replace(
            "ИНФОРМАЦИЯ О ТУРНИРЕ - ", "").replace("Tournament Information - ", "")
        tables = response.xpath('//div[@class="ratings"]//div[@style]')
        for table in tables:
            name = table.xpath(".//h1/text()").extract()
            if name == []:
                break
            name = name[0]
            tablecontent = table.xpath(".//table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody")
            for el in tablecontent.xpath(".//tr")[2:]:
                columnvalues = el.xpath(".//td//text()").extract()
                nickname = columnvalues[1]
                minus = columnvalues[5]
                sum_balls = columnvalues[2]
                sum_additional = columnvalues[3]
                plus = columnvalues[4]
                l_kh = columnvalues[6]
                c_i = columnvalues[7]
                victories = columnvalues[8]
                don_victories = columnvalues[9]
                sheriff_victories = columnvalues[10]
                killed = columnvalues[11]

                tableitem = items.TournamentTable()

                tableitem['tournament'] = tournament
                tableitem['user'] = nickname
                tableitem['tour'] = name
                tableitem['points'] = sum_balls
                tableitem['additional_points'] = sum_additional
                tableitem['positive_additional'] = plus
                tableitem['negative_additional'] = minus
                tableitem['l_kh'] = l_kh
                tableitem['don_victories'] = don_victories
                tableitem['sheriff_victories'] = sheriff_victories
                tableitem['first_shot'] = killed
                tableitem['c_i'] = c_i
                tableitem['victories'] = victories

                yield tableitem
        yield scrapy.Request(url=response.url.replace("results", "games"), callback=self.parse_results,
                             dont_filter=True)

    def parse_results(self, response):
        tournament = response.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/section[1]/div/div/div/h1/text()").extract_first().replace("ИНФОРМАЦИЯ О ТУРНИРЕ - ", "").replace("Tournament Information - ", "")
        resultable = response.xpath("//div[@class='alert alert-grey']/div[@class='tournament-stats-row']")
        most = '    '.join(resultable[0].xpath(".//span/text()").extract())
        most_red = '    '.join(resultable[1].xpath(".//span/text()").extract())
        most_black = '  '.join(resultable[2].xpath(".//span/text()").extract())
        most_killed = '    '.join(resultable[3].xpath(".//span/text()").extract())
        results = items.PlayersResult()
        results['tournament'] = tournament
        results['most_resultative'] = most
        results['best_kr'] = most_red
        results['best_bl'] = most_black
        results['most_killed'] = most_killed

        yield results
```

I have done some research, but I couldn't find any solution for my current problem.

Comment: This isn't an error it is a log.  And what it's saying is the server you are trying to connect to either isn't available or is actively refusing your connection.  Can you still visit the url with your browser?

Comment: @Alexander, yes, I can

Comment: the first line is the reason for the rest... the driver made a call to delete the session.  (it'd usually do this after driver.quit() is called...)

Comment: @pcalkins, do you know how to make it not to delete the session?

Comment: make sure you're not calling driver.quit() before you want to.  This could also be caused by a command timeout.  You'll have to debug a bit to figure it out.  Try/Catch all .get() calls.  If you find that's where the problem occurs, re-do the .get() call in the catch.